# Appmaker -How to populate options in dropdown from datasource based on the option selected from previous dropdown in Appmaker?

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-maker

I have 2 dropdowns Operating System and OS version namely. Each OS can have multiple OS versions and each OS version can be linked to more than one OS.

Once an OS is selected the OS version dropdown must get enabled and the options(OS versions) should be fetched from the datasource based on the OS selected above.

I tried using query script but how do I pass the client side value(selected option in OS i.e app.pages.RegisterServers.descendants.Dropdown8.value) to the query script?

[Image of form for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2BsW.png)

In the onClick event of OS dropdown I added the below code

```
   app.pages.RegisterServers.descendants.Dropdown9.enabled=true;
  app.datasources.OSVersion.query.parameters.os_name=
  app.pages.RegisterServers.descendants.Dropdown8.value;
```

And in the query script of OSVersion datasource I added a parameter os_name.

Query script code

```
  var osVersionResult = [];
 // Modify passed query to additionally filter by OS.
  query.filters.OpsName._equals=query.parameters.os_name;
  osVersionResult = query.run();
  return osVersionResult;
```

But this is not working. Please suggest if you see any reason for this.

Comment: Please don't answer your own question by extending your primary question. Instead perform an edit to the original question and delete your answer.

Comment: If you have a solution, then [accept an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), don't edit the word "Solved" into the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution!

Added below code in the OnValueChange event of OS drop down. Thats it, nothing else needs to be done.

```
app.pages.RegisterServers.descendants.Dropdown9.enabled=true;
app.datasources.OSVersion.query.filters.OpsName._equals=
app.pages.RegisterServers.descendants.Dropdown8.value;
app.datasources.OSVersion.load();
```